# '[AnyObject]?' does not have a member named 'Generator' XCode 6.4

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am using `XCode 6.4` version.

I am getting error in my code, please let me know what to fix.

```
class UserTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var users = [""]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    println(PFUser.currentUser())

    var query = PFUser.query()




    query!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        self.users.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

        for object in objects {
            var user:PFUser = object as PFUser
            self.users.append(user.username)
        }

        self.tableView.reloadData()

    })
}
```

> [AnyObject]?' does not have a member named 'Generator'

Comment: You're going to need to post more of your code than just this. Post the tableView functions as well.

Comment: `[AnyObject]` is different from `[AnyObject]?`. The latter is syntactic sugar for `Optional<[AnyObject]>` and an optional does not have a generator, that's what the error message tries to tel you (could be clearer IMO). That said you first need to unwrap the optional array using an if-let construct `if let actualObjects = objects { /* loop through actualObjects */ }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first make sure the array is not nil

```
if objects?.count > 0 {

for object in objects! {

// your code 

}
}
```